# How to pick one nested element from array in couchDb selector?

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-mango

I'm trying to write a filter to replicate the data to another CouchDB server. As part of filter, I would like to pick only certain parts of the document, based on the filter. The `fields` in `Selector` can fetch the root nodes, but how can I pick nested elements?

These are sample docs structure:

```
{
    "_id" : "1231212",
    "name" : "",
    "a" : [
    {
      "x" : "123",
      "y": "123" ,
      "z" : 123"",
      "l" : [1, 2, 3]
    },
    {
      "x" : "456",
      "y": "456" ,
      "z" : "456",
      "l" : [4, 5, 6]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
{
    "_id" : "34534545",
    "name" : "",
    "a" : [
    {
      "x" : "222",
      "y": "333" ,
      "z" : 444"",
      "l" : [6, 7, 8]
    },
    {
      "x" : "66",
      "y": "66" ,
      "z" : "888",
      "l" : [2, 9, 7]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to put a selector to pick fields, which is an element from array. In above Doc structure, I can filter the data with element in Array "l", but how I can only display that element.

```
{
   "selector": {
    "a": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "l": {
                "$in": [
                4
                ]
            }
        }
    }
  },
   "fields": [
      "name",
      "a"
   ]
}
```

if I use this selector, which give both elements of "a" array. But I need only the filtered element.

For the above filter, I'm expecting:

```
{
    name : "",
    "a" : [
    {
      "x" : "456",
      "y": "456" ,
      "z" : "456",
      "l" : [4, 5, 6]
    }
  ]
}
```

what I'm getting is

```
{
    "_id" : "1231212",
    "name" : "",
    "a" : [
    {
      "x" : "123",
      "y": "123" ,
      "z" : 123"",
      "l" : [1, 2, 3]
    },
    {
      "x" : "456",
      "y": "456" ,
      "z" : "456",
      "l" : [4, 5, 6]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You cannot replicate partial documents. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: yes, thanks for replying